# How to determine the "content" of an email?

Tags: email, parsing, artificial-intelligence

I've been curious about something for a bit, that has to do with Gmail (and other clients) when displaying the content of an email.

How do they determine what is the "content" and what is the "footer" or replies/signature/etc.? What I mean is that when looking at an email that is from someone personally, Gmail will almost always, perfectly, hide the signature by default but still allow you to expand the email to see it. How do they know what to hide and what not to hide?

My Google-fu isn't working for me here, I think I'm using the wrong words maybe? I thought maybe there was something about the HTML content of the email but that clearly wouldn't be reliable, plus it works just as well with text/plain emails.

What's the "trick"?

Comment: I suspect that you've tagged your question with the right tag. I guess the approach is, essentially, to just [STACK MORE LAYERS](https://i.redd.it/5193db0avbey.jpg)

Comment: @AndreyTyukin I really wish I understood that. I want it to be funny. ;-)

Comment: @Brian The essential technique is to [guess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heuristic). There are common-sense approaches, as well as statistical and machine-leaning approaches, to guessing correctly more often than not.

Comment: [I guess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heuristic_(computer_science)) this link is more apropos.

Comment: @jpaugh I mean, if you have machine learning techniques powerful enough to segment complex 3D scenes in video so that you can drive a car through that scene without bumping into anything, then it should be completely trivial to segment a short piece of text into "content" and "signature" part. I mean, run with some kind of LSTM through the email once, let it output '0' for each content line and a '1' for each line of signature. Done. Something along those lines. Is there any reason why google wouldn't just throw some monstrous neural network on the task?

Comment: At this point, yes. But, I can't help but wonder whether they used something much less sophisticated at the time GMail was built. Signatures are handled well by virtually every email client; and GMail has been around for far longer than their Go algorithm, for example.

Comment: @jpaugh well, yes, one could think of thousand other ways to accomplish that. It's actually an indication that the question is too broad.

Comment: Probably relevant: [Learning to Extract Signature and Reply Lines from Email](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~vitor/papers/sigFilePaper_submited.pdf) , [Segmenting Email Message Text into Zones](https://aclanthology.info/pdf/D/D09/D09-1096.pdf) .

Comment: I figured these might be the answers, looks like I've got quite a learning task ahead of me.